# Simple Python script - Adding a primitive object to the active layer

Tags: python, scripting

I use great "Pie Menu Editor" addon and in the "command" section I would like to add command that adds a primitive object to the scene, but only to the active layer.

Default code that can be copied from the "Info" window allows to specify to which layers a new object can be assigned, but does not allow to specify the currently active one.

Thank you for Your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click on the add cube icon and then click **Pie Menu Editor**.

[image]

then it will ask you in which menu you want to put it.

[image]

by default the the arguments for layers are all False
[image]

so unless you specify one it will always create the cube in the activate layer
[image]

Comment: Thank you this was a good suggestion from Your side.